# Dynamic CSS in CSS Modules when coming from Styled Components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components, css-modules

The following question came up when I wanted to migrate from Styled Components to CSS Modules.

Let's say I have the following styled component which accepts a dynamic parameter `offset` and a dynamic CSS string `theme`:

```
const Li = styled.li`
  &.selected {
    background-color: grey;
  }

  margin-left: ${({ offset }) => offset}px;

  ${({ theme }) => theme};
`;
```

In my code, I'd use it the following way:

```
const Parent = () => (
  <List>
    {list.map((item) => (
      <Item
        key={item.id}
        id={item.id}
        selectedIds={[]}
        offset={24}
        theme={`
          &.selected {
            background-color: green;
          }
        `}
      >
        {item.name}
      </Item>
    ))}
  </List>
);

const Item = ({ id, offset = 0, theme, children }) => {
  return (
    <Li
      theme={theme}
      offset={offset}
      className={selectedIds.includes(id) && 'selected'}
    >
      {children}
    </Li>
  );
};
```

**Requirement:** Now I would really keep the `Item`'s component API: passing a `number` offset and a style string `theme`. So essentially everything in `Parent` component should stay this way.

How can I convert the `Item` component internally to use CSS Modules instead of the styled `Li` component?

Answer (score 10):

It's probably a different way of thinking than you used to but it can work

1. You can use css variable

```
style={{ [`--offset`]: `${offset}px` }}
```

```css
.item {
  margin-left: var(--offset);
}
```

2. You can have a css module (file) dedicated to themes. In your case, it has `withSelected`

```css
.withSelected {
  &.selected {
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

So you could pass it as "theme"

```
theme={themes.withSelected}
```

This is how the components look

```
import styles from "./style.module.scss";
import themes from "./themes.module.scss";

const Parent = () => (
  <ul>
    {list.map((item) => (
      <Item
        key={item.id}
        id={item.id}
        selectedIds={[1]}
        offset={24}
        theme={themes.withSelected}
      >
        {item.name}
      </Item>
    ))}
  </ul>
);

const Item = ({ id, offset = 0, theme, children, selectedIds }) => {
  return (
    <li
      className={`${styles.item} ${theme} ${
        selectedIds.includes(id) && themes.selected
      }`}
      style={{ [`--offset`]: `${offset}px` }}
    >
      {children}
    </li>
  );
};
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/styledcomponent-to-css-modules-1kbqx

Comment: Thanks for the answers Mosh! The 1. solution would be a good way of doing it! For the 2., I would expect something more ambiguous than having to use CSS Modules for passing it as theme. I would want to pass it as style string as I have done in the question. How can I pick this up in Item component then?

Comment: Edited the question to reflect more what I want to achieve here.

Comment: There is an advantage of the possibility to pass css as prop (I'm not sure how scalable it is though). But, one of the differences in styledComponents ("SC") is that js involved so you can manipulate the styles in runtime. So SC gives you (1) runtime manipulations (2) css scoping. css-modules like vanilla css is static and gives you only css-scoping. That's why a new actually, old) way of thinking required when you move from SC to css-modules.

Comment: Won't work with typescript

Comment: @MegaProger what do you mean by "won't work with typescript"? Would you mind to elaborate? I made a [snippet with a ts version](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-n3sv4x?file=src%2FApp.tsx,src%2FComponent.tsx&terminal=dev) for the discussion

Answer (score 1):

With 1 I'd concur with @Mosh to just use the style prop. Css modules are static by design and there no way to get this done otherwise (I think that styled-components also uses the style prop so you're not losing anything).

For 2 you can leverage Sass modules which allow you to define your theme in a single place and import them as required:

`/theme/_colors.scss`

```
$red: rgb(200, 0 50);
```

`/components/Item.module.scss`

```
@import "../theme/colors"

.selected {
    background: $red;
}
```

Note: if you use [Create React App absolute paths](https://dev.to/mr_frontend/absolute-imports-in-create-react-app-3ge8) you can import from root as `~theme/colors`